# What's the directory location for Newsstand documents?

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage

I saved a few magazine issues using the options available in the Google Play Newsstand app, but can't figure out where the files are stored. Nothing showed up in the `/sdcard/` directories tagged with recent modification dates.

Anyone know where I should be looking? In case it's relevant, my device is ASUS MemoPad 302C.

Comment: The magazines are not available for offline access and they are not stored in the phone memory I guess based on [this post](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/producer/bcIFOkxkRUs/5eer_Ne1DwAJ)

Comment: @Lucky  Definitely not true, since I can click on "download to read later" and read them offline.

Comment: Yeah I checked it with my pre-installed Newstand app and agree with you. I said I guessed it based on that post, but sorry that it's not true. But I could find anything inside the data folder `Android/data/com.google.android.apps.magazines`. I'm not rooted too so I can't check. Wait for someone with root permissions to post an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Without root access on the device, probably nowhere. With root, most likely in `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.magazines`. If the app stores data on sdcard, it should be found below `Android/data/com.google.android.apps.magazines`.

Comment: Well, it's not in the latter.  I'm not rooted, and can't do so w/o the fancy image over at xda-dev, so I may just have to live w/ things as they are.

Answer (score 0):

It'll probably be in `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.magazines` as **Izzy** says. I want to point something out in here, further improving his answer.

A-) All apps, by default, store their datas in `/data/data/*app's package name*`

B-) Yet, if they have the required permission given by the user, they can use `/sdcard` partition as they wish to store data as well.

A is a default case.

B however, is optional. B is usually preferred when the created data file must be easily accessible by the user (like Whatsapp backups, images etc.) or when the app needs to download additional files to work properly (e.g. game patches)

This applies to **all user apps** therefore the information you try to find is either in somewhere in `/sdcard` or in the related `/data` folder that is `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.magazines`

Comment: Thanks -- guess I'm SOL unless I find a simple rooter for my ASUS tablet.